# I want to open phone gallery whenever user will click on input field of website

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, asp.net

Now I am using

```
<input type="file" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg"/>
```

for accepting a image. For this input I am getting different behaviour in different browser. Sometime its open drive and sometime its open folder type structure but I want to open gallery everytime. Gallery will be helpful for any user for my use case.

Someone please guide me.

Comment: what do you mean by "gallery" here? The layout of the file system on the client-side computer is not information you can EVER get. You can't even set the folder, or even the file name. If you could do this, then when I visit your cute cat pictures site, you would be able to search around on MY computer and steal files. My files and my computer is not your computer, and your web site can't mess around with looking for folders or even set what folder(s) I have on my computer. Perhaps next you go looking for files called mypassword? or my banking folder? So client folders are 100% hands off.

Comment: Only the user can select files and folders - you can't do this from the web site side, the user must always make such selections - you have no means to select folders, set folders, or set file names. These are 100% controlled by the user and client side, and if this was not the case, then the internet would be too dangerous to use. Settings for what picture or whatever the user selected is THEIR settings on THEIR phone - you can't change this from the web site at all

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<input type="file" id="id" name="id"  accept="image/png,image/jpeg" capture="filesystem">
```

Comment: I have tried but its opening camera.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/png,image/jpeg" />
```